# Accessing Freemarker root objects with loop

Tags: java, freemarker

Using Freemarker and Java. I have entries in my root Map like the following:

```
DAY_1=2018/05/01
VOLUME_1=123456
VALUE_1=456.78
DAY_2=2018/05/02
VOLUME_2=654321
VALUE_2=876.54
...
DAY_N=2018/05/20
VOLUME_N=555555
VALUE_N=333.44
```

and want to output these in a comma separated list like the following:

```
2018/05/01,123456,456.78
2018/05/02,654321,876.54
...
2018/05/20,555555,333.44
```

I thought this would be easy to iterate over in my FTL template file using a simple loop iterator specifying the static part of the key "DAY_" and concatenating the index value from the loop index.

I have searched for several hours for a strategy for how to do this and attempted many FTL coding styles but get nothing but errors. Maybe I'm overthinking this, too.

Any suggestions on a simple approach to accessing this Map data?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming N is at least 1 (otherwise use exclusive end range, like `1 ..< N+1`):

```
<#list 1..N as i>
  ${.data_model['DAY_${i?c}']},${.data_model['VOLUME_${i?c}']},${.data_model['VALUE_${i?c}']}
</#list>
```

Or, some prefers using `.vars` instead, which also check variables in the current namespace and local and loop variables.

But I would recommend using a data-model that contains a `List` of `Map`-s, or a `List` of Java beans instead. That's how it meant to be, as far as FreeMarker is concerned.

Comment: Thank you! That goes a long way to solving my problem. One last thing I need to figure out is how to count "DAY_xx" entries to supply the N value. If I specify a value larger than my data set I get a Freemarker "The following has evaluated to null or missing:" Are there any nifty features to count entries in the data_model's key set based on a string pattern?

Comment: There's no special feature to extract the highest N. Your data-model is rather unusual, as I said. But, assuming the index range has no gaps, you can do this: `<#list 1..99999999 as i><#if !(.data_model['DAY_${i?c}']??)><#break></#if>...</#list>`

Comment: I'm not particularly thrilled with the data model either and can see the design goes against better design practices.  I ended up adding a count key/value pair and using thay value in the 1..N loop range.